# Fiori Extension calling an Entityset value before aggregation binding of the list item

Tags: javascript, data-binding, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am a newbie in Fiori and working on a standard Fiori App extension. It is a Master ->Detail App. In my masterview I am able to bind the list with the odata. below is my code

```
this.searchFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilterSName], true); this.oList.bindAggregation("items", { path: '/entityset1', template: this.oListItem, filters: this.searchFilters });
```

this is absolutely working fine however there is a value called "serialNo" in the /entityset1 which I need to get before the entityset1 gets binded to the list. My Idea is If I am able to get the "serialNo" then I will need to query another entityset ( entityset2) to fetch a different value and bind to another element in the masterview.

Could some one advise how to get the value. this is a standard fiori app and this is an unnamed model. I have tried this.getView.getModel() in the onInit() and onAfterRendering but I am getting undefined error. Could some one please provide me to an example app or provide some snippet to get the value from the entityset1.

Comment: Where do you create and see the model ? You should set it on the component and then you should be able to get it in the onInit method

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi Yes I have created in Component and trying to access, however I am unable to get the data of the . I am using . odata.getModel("myModel").getProperty("sName"); and unfortunately getting undefined error.

Comment: Try to access the data using this.getOwnerComponent().get model("my model")

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to use the [$expand](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html#loiobf1fc3b4c9ab4bbc845a3f0e0940c004) url parameter to get data from both entitysets at same time.

```
this.searchFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilterSName], true);
this.oList.bindAggregation("items", {
  path: '/entityset1',
  template: this.oListItem,
  filters: this.searchFilters,
  parameters: {
    expand: "/entityset2" //$expand to /entityset2
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Alex thank you for the response. this is what I am looking for however am getting an error.  ..ERROR_INFO The URI is violating the construction rules defined in the Data Services specification

Comment: Can you post your Request URI?

Comment: This is the URI ----          /sap/opu/odata/sap/zsfile_srv/EntitySet1?$skip=0&$top=20&$filter=(substringof(%27ana%27,SearchText))&$expand=%2fEntitySet2&$inlinecount=allpages

Comment: Ideally the data from EntitySet2 will only be retrieved with the $filter "StuNUmber" from the EntitySet1, that is where my big struggle.

/EntitySet2?$skip=0&$top=20&$filter=(StuNumber="21301212")&$inlinecount=allpages

Comment: Your Filter seems to be wrong. It should be something like this: `(StuNumber eq '21301212')` How did you create this filter?

Comment: thats true,  it should be exatly like this .. sorry Its my mistake...  (StuNumber eq '21301212')